# c programming for loop with multiple conditions

Tags: c, lcd, state-machine

I have an foor loop in a finite state machine:

```
if (nextstate != state)
{
    state = nextstate;
    for (i=0; menu_state[i].state; i++)
    {
        if (menu_state[i].state == state)
        {
            statetext =  menu_state[i].pText;
            pStateFunc = menu_state[i].pFunc;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

The state machine is use for showing an menu on a LCD display. (I have used an example I found online for the state machine and adapted it for my micocontroler system).

Everyting works fine and the menu system works, but I would now like to add the adjacent textlines in the menu (to make it easier to see where you are in the menu). 
(the original menu was for an 1 row display and I have a 5 row display).

So my conclusion is that I need to adapt this for loop.

This is what I came up with:

```
if (nextstate != state)
{
    state = nextstate;

    for (i=0,a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4; menu_statetop[i].state; i++,a++,b++,c++,d++)
    {

        if (menu_statetop[i].state == state)
        {
            statetext=  menu_statetop[i].pText;
            statetext2=  menu_statetop[a].pText;
            statetext3=  menu_statetop[b].pText;
            statetext4=  menu_statetop[c].pText;
            statetext5=  menu_statetop[d].pText;

            pStateFunc = menu_statetop[i].pFunc;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This seems to work more or less... but the problem is the boundary. Because in the look up table there are 5 lines. 
and when the variabels are becoming bigger than this MAX (4) value they are outside valid lookuptable MAX value and shows garbage.

I am trying to find a elegant solution for this. Any ideas?
I have considered using if statements but all look so...messy...
big and clumpsy code...

So what I am trying to achieve is for example when "a" becomes 4 it should become 0. and next time the for loop runs it should become 1. 
same for b, c and d. and they should maintain the same "distance" from each other(when b is 2 c should be 3, d should be 4 etc.)

Same idea but oposite for the MIN(0) value.

Anyone have any ideas how to do something like this in a good way?

Comment: another way to do state machines is to use a switch with the different states e.g. `switch (mystate) { case 1: if (somecond) mystate=2; break; ... }`

Comment: For a state machine with a limited number of states (say:20) and transitions (say:50), it is often simpler to just hardcode the whole thing into a giant `switch()`

Comment: thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the messy `int a` etc you can do

```
menu_statetop[(i + 1) % 5].pText;
menu_statetop[(i + 2) % 5].pText;
menu_statetop[(i + 3) % 5].pText;
```

and so on.

EDIT:
This also takes care of the menu overflow by ensuring it "wraps" back to the start. As well as accessing the next menu item(s) with `i + 1` etc it uses the modulus (or remainder) operator `%` to achieve this.

Comment: Gonna drop my two cents here, I think it's useful to add a bit of explanation. Seeing as OP is possibly newer to C programming, I really doubt they are aware of the uses of the modulus. Maybe a small note as to what (i + 1) % 5 means?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use one single variable to control your for loop increment :

```
    for (i=0; menu_statetop[i].state; i++)
```

As answered by Weather Vane, you can then handle the array index offset in the body of the for loop. This is much clearer and more robust.

I would also be careful with the variable that you use as a condition for your for loop.
in you code you use the menu_statetop[i].state variable which seems to be an integer/enum.
If there were no "break;" in the loop, the for loop would be executed as long as the value contained in menu_statetop[i].state is not equal to 0.